# variable not recognised when plotting graph

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, input

I have a user input function to extract 3 rows of data from a table and assigned this data to the variable 'all_sectors'. When I try to use this variable to plot the data on a bar chart it comes up with the following error message:

Unrecognized function or variable 'all_sectors'.

Error in train_fares_script (line 36)
y = all_sectors ;

My code to select the data is:

```
if year == 2004 
    all_sectors = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",'sheet','2004','range','A1:A3')
elseif year == 2005 
    year = 2005
    all_sectors = readmatrix("train_fares.xlsx",'sheet','2005','range','A1:A3')
```

My code to plot this on a bar graph is:

x = categorical({'London and South East','Long Distance','Regional'});
y = all_sectors ;
bar(x,y)
How can I fix this so the variable is recognised?

Ive tried copying and pasting the variable name to ensure it is spelled correctly and changed the name to see if that would work but it hasn't.

Comment: Is the data selection code in a function? If so, is the plotting code in the same function?

Comment: @Pursuit the data selection code is in a function but the plotting code is not in a function- i have used this structure before in previous code and it has worked fine

Comment: Is the `all_sectors` variable an output of the function? What are you naming the output in the parent workspace?

Comment: @Pursuit the output in the parent workspace is a bar chart with the data of ‘all_sectors’ plotted on it- the variable is an output of the function

Comment: Is the function supposed to return `all_sectors`? Or it supposed to display/return a bar chart? or both?

Comment: @magnesium the first function is meant to return all_sectors and the second is meant to return a bar chart of the data all_sectors

Comment: Please consider looking back at your previous question - it looks like this `if` sequence is working around your earlier issue and over-complicating your code. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], it's likely that `year` never satisfies one of your `if` conditions, so `all_sectors` is never created. But without a complete example it's impossible for us to verify this. Note also that the answer I left to your previous question would avoid the need for this workaround anyway which might help